# No duplicates in list of images

Tags: php

I have a piece of code that pulls a set of images from a directory. 
Problem is, it allows duplicates which I do not want. 
Anybody an idea how to let every image be unique?
Can’t seem to figure it out right away with my limited knowledge. thanks!

```
 <?php
$files = glob("images/*.*");

for($x = 0 ; $x < 4; $x++)
{

$fileNum=rand(1, count($files));
$image = $files[$fileNum];

echo '<img src="'.$image .'" id="lay"/>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want four random files from the array to echo out. I suggest you use `array_rand(4)` to get four random keys from the list.

```
$files = glob("images/*.*");
$keys = array_rand(4);
foreach ($keys as $key) {
    $image = $files[$key];
    echo '<img src="'.$image .'" id="lay"/>';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead:

```
<?php
$files = glob("images/*.*");

foreach ( $files as $file )
{
echo '<img src="'. $file .'" id="lay"/>';
}
?>
```

Hope I could help you!